# como passar multiplas consultas do banco de dados a uma rota?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize-js

## Problema:

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação no Nodejs + Express e cheguei a uma etapa em que preciso passar diversas consultas ao banco de dados por uma unica rota.

OBS: utilizo o ORM Sequelize para realizar essas tarefas com o banco e não possuo muito conhecimento com promisses ou funções assíncronas.

#### abaixo segue o código que tentei implementar, porém não deu certo:

```
app.get('/monitoramento', eUsuario, (req, res) => {
    
    Bloco2.findAll({limit: 1, order: [['updatedAt', 'desc']]}) +
    Bloco1.findAll({limit: 1, order: [['updatedAt', 'desc']]}).then((bloco1, bloco2) => {
        res.render('monitoramento', {bloco1: bloco1, bloco2: bloco2})
    }).catch((err) => {
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Não foi possível listar dados.')
        res.redirect('/homepage')
    })
})
```

alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você realizar duas consultas e depois fazer algo com os resultados, você pode usar [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas).

Os resultados das consultas serão armazenados nas variáveis correspondentes e você pode fazer N consultas, cada uma de maneira individual. O `await` é necessário para aguardar a consulta ser concluída e você poder obter a resposta (como no `.then()`).

```
app.get('/monitoramento', eUsuario, async (req, res) => {

    const bloco2 = await Bloco2.findAll({limit: 1, order: [['updatedAt', 'desc']]});
    const bloco1 = await Bloco1.findAll({limit: 1, order: [['updatedAt', 'desc']]});

    // Faça algo com as respostas bloco1 e bloco2
});
```

Outra opção é o encadeamento de `.then()`. Abaixo dou um exemplo de `.then()` aninhados:

```
app.get('/monitoramento', eUsuario, (req, res) => {

    Bloco2.findAll({limit: 1, order: [['updatedAt', 'desc']]}).then(bloco2 => {
        // Faça algo aqui com o bloco2

        Bloco1.findAll({limit: 1, order: [['updatedAt', 'desc']]}).then(bloco1 => {
            // Faça algo aqui com o bloco1 e bloco2
        });

    });;

});
```

Obviamente a solução mais legível é com async/await :)

Comment: muito obrigado resolveu aqui!